# Problem in using Python Multiprocessing package to parse text files

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In one of my research projects, I am trying to count certain words from 170,000 text files. I have a functional for loop to do the job but it is painful to watch only 20% of the CPU is being used:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
def normalize_text(text):
    some process to normalize the text
    return text
# I created a filelist dataframe prior to execute this function
def countwords(filelist):
    global wc
    header_list=['file','wda', 'wdb', 'wdc', 'wdd', 'wde','wdf']
    wc=pd.DataFrame()
    wc = wc.reindex(columns = header_list) 
    for i in range(filelist.shape[0]):
        words = ['wda', 'wdb', 'wdc', 'wdd', 'wde','wdf']
        count={}
        for elem in words:
            count[elem] = 0
        file=open(filelist.iloc[i].at['location'], encoding='latin-1')
        full=file.read()    
        text=normalize_text(full)
        for word in words:
            count[word] = len(re.findall(word,text))
        wc = wc.append(count, sort=False,ignore_index=True)
        wc=wc
```

I am trying to modify my code to use the multiprocessing package see if I can process multiple files at a time.
I am new to the package, here is a modified version:

```
import re
def countwords(filedest):
    words = ['wda', 'wdb', 'wdc', 'wdd', 'wde','wdf']
    count={}
    for elem in words:
        count[elem] = 0
    count.update({'file' : filedest})
    file=open(filedest, encoding='latin-1')
    full=file.read()    
    text=normalize_text(full)
    for word in words:
      count[word] = len(re.findall(word,text))
    return count

mydir = os.path.join('C:\\',"filedest\*.txt")
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import glob2

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tasks = glob2.glob(str(mydir))
  pool = ThreadPool()
  results=pool.map_async(countwords,tasks)
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
#results are handled after pool.join
```

I noticed the code is being processed for an abnormal amount of time, after keyboard interruption, the code continues to run for a while and finishes the job, (however if I do not interrupt it will keep hanging for infinite time and explode my memory). 
I have tried switching between processpool and threadpool, warp the result with another function but does not seem to be of any use.
I am using anaconda distribution with Spyder IDE.
I appreciate your time and help

Comment: threads in Python don't work faster if they need mostly CPU (not read/write to file/url) because Python use `GIL` to run only one thread at a time.

Comment: It seems like your "while True" loop will keep launching tasks forever with the same arguments.  Just call the line below it without the while.  You don't show your code that handles the results object, but I assume you've read the docs on how to handle that to wait for the subprocesses to complete.  I think furas' comment is wrong.  The docs say that multiprocessing launches separate processes, not threads, and so the GIL isn't a problem.

Comment: I use multithread in downloading those files and it made the process considerably faster so I just kept using it.@furas

Comment: @electrogas I tried without the while true statement it runs just like the old code. The results are aggregated after the pool.join, could that be the problem?

Comment: If your CPU usage is low, this is generally a sign that you are IO bound. Adding processes to access more CPUs is not going to help in this case. Adding threads may help, but only if the bottleneck is actually your application, not the media you are reading from.

Comment: Take note that instead of using a dataframe, reading the entire file at once and throwing regular expressions at it — you might just use a collections.Counter on a generator splitting the stream of file-lines by words, and filtering out the undesired words with a set containment.

Comment: Thank you @MisterMiyagi, I will follow those suggestions,  I am most concerned about the part that allows me to add threads to the code, it seems to be working but just hangs on the pool.join and wouldn't quit properly. Do you know what's happening there?

Comment: you did not  perform a file.close() in your  countwords, which means your script will hold every opened file handle ,  likely to be the reason of exploding your memory

Comment: and setting a proper chunksize arg for map_asycn may help too,  to reduce   IO  impact on your media  storing the text files